# Error with aggregation using CASE in sqldf in R

Tags: r

I want to identify source wise traffic and for that I need to group different traffic sources using case when is there a way I can do it in R, my code below is throwing error

```
grouped_sources <- sqldf("SELECT 
       CASE WHEN First_Source_ = 'undefined' THEN 'Undefined'
       WHEN First_Source_ = ' Internet ' THEN 'Interner'
       WHEN First_Source_ = 'Friend' THEN 'Friend'
       WHEN First_Source_ IN ('Google','adwords','google') THEN 'Google'
       WHEN First_Source_ = 'Former Student' THEN 'Former Student'
       WHEN First_Source_ IN('Facebook','facebook') THEN 'Facebook'
       WHEN First_Source_ IS NULL THEN 'Null'
       ELSE 'Other' END CASE AS Source, COUNT(*) AS Count 
       FROM turnover 
       GROUP BY First_Source_,CASE WHEN First_Source_ = 'undefined' THEN 'Undefined'
       WHEN First_Source_ = ' Internet ' THEN 'Interner'
       WHEN First_Source_ = 'Friend' THEN 'Friend'
       WHEN First_Source_ IN ('Google','adwords','google') THEN 'Google'
       WHEN First_Source_ = 'Former Student' THEN 'Former Student'
       WHEN First_Source_ IN('Facebook','facebook') THEN 'Facebook'
       WHEN First_Source_ IS NULL THEN 'Null'
       ELSE 'Other'")
```

This keeps throwing Error: near "CASE": syntax error is anyone facing a similar issue while using case when in R????

Answer (score 1):

As the error message indicates the CASE statement does not have correct syntax.  It is missing the `END`.